# C# XmlReader confused about assigning values from read() function

Tags: c#, xml, tuples, xmlreader

Have the following code, new to this so be kind, it looks clunky and isn't returning what I expect it to return. Basically I'm trying to read nodes for Operator, Password, and Group values into vars and return via a tuple.

```
public static Tuple<string, string, string> ReadSecurity()
{            
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("Operator.xml");
    string sOperator = "";
    string sPassword = "";
    string sGroup = "";

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Security")
        {
            while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                reader.Read();
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                {
                    sOperator = reader.Value;
                }

                reader.Read();
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                {
                    sPassword = reader.Value;
                }

                reader.Read();
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                {
                    sGroup = reader.Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Tuple.Create(sOperator, sPassword, sGroup);
}
```

Seem to be missing the first value each time but have no idea how to change this, online tutorials are assuming a lot more knowledge than I currently have.

For example:
See below for the current iteration (yes, I know the password should be encrypted).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Security ver="beta"> 
    <Operator>Ted</Operator> 
    <Password>password</Password> 
    <Group>op</Group> 
</Security>
```

Comment: Show us an xml example.

Comment: In the future please add additional information as edits to the question and not as comments.

Comment: Need a few samples of the operator and password if they are in the same file.

Comment: It's going to be **much much easier** to stream through the file, find each `<Security>` elements, and them with `XElement.ReadFrom()`.  See e.g. [How to read large xml file without loading it in memory and using XElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18282052) and [Get the EndElement Node of an XElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40070665).

Comment: Side note: "...the password should be encrypted" is awful practice for most cases, especially for implementing homemade authentication... but you probably also know it already.

Comment: Unless the XML you're reading is huge (which looks unlikely), I'd suggest you use LINQ to XML rather than `XmlReader`. This is very low-level stuff that's fiddly to write, resulting in issues like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a breakpoint at the beginning of your method and run it step by step pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>. You will see that the `XmlReader` reads, among others, the `Whitespace` nodes. See Debug > Windows > Autos or Locals window.

You must ignore these `Whitespace` nodes and correctly navigate to nodes of type `Text`, to read their values. You also need to correctly handle start and end tags.

As a result, the code might look like this:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("Operator.xml"))
{
    string sOperator = "";
    string sPassword = "";
    string sGroup = "";

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Operator")
        {
            reader.Read(); // move to Text node
            sOperator = reader.Value;
        }

        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Password")
        {
            reader.Read(); // move to Text node
            sPassword = reader.Value;
        }

        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Group")
        {
            reader.Read(); // move to Text node
            sGroup = reader.Value;
        }
    }

    return Tuple.Create(sOperator, sPassword, sGroup);
}
```

---

However the `XmlReader` class has many useful methods. If you use them correctly, you can make its use simple and enjoyable.

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("Operator.xml"))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("Operator");
    var sOperator = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

    reader.ReadToFollowing("Password");
    var sPassword = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

    reader.ReadToFollowing("Group");
    var sGroup = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

    return Tuple.Create(sOperator, sPassword, sGroup);
}
```